# (Python) How to cut each line in a file into thirds and add each third to a different list?

Tags: python

I've got an assignment to create a Dadaist cutup program in Python, which cuts a file into thirds vertically and reshuffles them. I'm trying to read every line in the file, divide it into thirds, and add each third to a different list. This is my code for that part:

```
lorem = open("lorem.txt","r")
lorem.readlines()

a = []
b = []
c = []

for line in lorem:
    n = int(len(line) / 3)
    splits = [line[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(line), n)]
    a.append(splits[0])
    b.append(splits[1])
    c.append(splits[2])

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)

lorem.close()
```

I've printed the lists to see if the cut up lines are being added, but it just prints 3 empty lists. I'm not getting any error messages so I'm unable to determine what the problem is. Any explanation would be extremely helpful, I've really fallen behind in the subject with everything going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `readlines`, you read through all the contents of the file, moving the file pointer to the end of the file. You're getting empty lists at the end of your script because once you arrive at the `for` loop, you've already moved the file pointer over the entire file -- there's nothing to loop over. Check out the [documentation on methods of file objects](https://cdn.spincar.com/wa-development/deleteme_test_customer_crunsa5f/kvykjmaj/20200429195201.PF9CVOFK/closeups/cu-0.jpg).

If you want to call `readlines`, then instead of this:

```
lorem = open(...)
lorem.readlines()
...
for line in lorem:
```

you need to do

```
with open(...) as f:  # This will close the file for you
    lorem = f.readlines()  # Store the contents of the file in a variable
...
for line in lorem:
```

You can also loop over the file object itself:

```
with open(...) as f:
    for line in f:
        ...
```

Comment: That's fixed the empty list problem and the explanation is really helpful, thank you for that. 

I chose readlines() instead of read() because I need to cut each individual line into thirds, not the text itself into thirds. However now each list contains a single string containing an unbroken third of the text, rather than several strings each containing a third of a line. Is there a way to improve my code to accomplish that?

Comment: `readlines` puts each line of text into a list. Your code should still do what you thought it was doing before. If I were you, I would make it simpler and simply do: `one_third = int(len(line) / 3)` `a.append(line[:one_third])` `b.append(line[one_third: 2 * one_third])` `...`. I think that makes it much clearer what's going on, and is a fine solution if you only ever need to break the lines into thirds.

Comment: @CampbellMilne Forgot to tag you above ^. Separately, if this answer or any other answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I've realised that I was using an unbroken paragraph to test it, with no line breaks which was what was causing the problem. Thank you for your help, I've marked it as accepted!

Comment: @CampbellMilne No problem!